# How to split Combinations with repetition task, in case of a type limitation? Different ways to count Combination with repetitions?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Currently I am struggling to undestand **Combination with repetition**, and I feel confused if the task changes just a bit.

It seems like distinguishing the patterns and being able to split the task into the sub-tasks and count them separately is crucial (however, the combinatorics [calculator](https://molbiotools.com/math_calculators/combinatoricscalculator.php) do help).

**EXAMPLE-1:**

> The bag has `3 cyan`, `3 magenta`, `3 yellow` and `3 key/black`
> (**CMYK**) balls.
>
> I can choose `3 balls`.
>
> How many **combinations** can I get?

**Answer**: The problem can be re-formulated as **how many combinations can I get if I choose 3 balls from cyan, magenta, yellow and key/black categories (four colors)**, since I've got enough balls of each color. So I have `k=3` balls to choose from `n=4` colors.

**SOLUTION-1**: Then the straightforward way is to use **Combination with repetition** formula *[which can be easily transformed into combination without repetition formula]*:
$$C_r(n,k)=\left[{_{k+n-1}C_{k}}=\binom{k+n-1}{k}={_{k+n-1}C_{n-1}}\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}\right]=\frac{(k+n-1)!}{k!(n-1)}=\frac{(3+4-1)!}{3!(4-1)!}=\frac{3!\times6\times5\times4}{3!\times6}=20$$

That is more or less evident.

**SOLUTION-2**: Spliting into sub-tasks of **Combination without repetition** (I've found a similar approch [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2766608/1137447)).

a). All colors are different (CMY,CMK,...) = ${_nC_k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = {_4C_3} = 4$

b). Only two colors are the same (CCM,CCY,...) = ${_4C_1} \times {_3C_1} = 4\times3 = 12$

c). All colors are the same (CCC,MMM,...) = ${_4C_1} = 4$

Total = $4+12+4=20$, right?

I use the sum of **Combinations without repetition** to get the same result. Are there any other ways to get the same result with some other formulas (permutation with repetition minus ***something*** probably)?

**EXAMPLE-2:**

> The bag has `1 cyan`, `3 magenta`, `3 yellow` and `3 key/black`
> (**CMYK**) balls.
>
> I can choose `3 balls`.
>
> How many **combinations** can I get?

Am I right that I should tackle the problem like in **Solution-2** only?

a). All colors are different (CMY,CMK,...) = ${_nC_k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = {_4C_3} = 4$

b). Only two colors are the same (`cyan` not counting) (MMC,MMY,...) = ${_4C_1} \times {_3C_1}-3 = 4\times3-3 = 9$

c). All colors are the same (`cyan` not counting) (MMM,YYY...) = ${_4C_1}-1 = 4-1 = 3$

Total = $4+9+3=16$, or do I miss anything? Or, if you were me, would you tackle the problem in any other, probably more efficient/interesting, way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the work you did is correct.

For the second example, there are a couple of approaches you could take.

**Method 1:**  Consider cases, depending on how many cyan balls are selected.  Let $c, m, y, k$ denote, respectively, the number of selected balls which are cyan, magenta, yellow, key/black.

If no cyan balls are selected, then
$$m + y + k = 3,$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{3 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{5}{2}$$
solutions.

If exactly one cyan ball is selected, then two balls must be selected from the remaining three colors, so
$$m + y + k = 2,$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{2 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{4}{2}$$
solutions.

In total, the number of ways three balls can be selected from one cyan ball, three magenta balls, three yellow balls, and three key/black balls is
$$\binom{5}{2} + \binom{4}{2} = 10 + 6 = 16$$
as you found.

**Method 2:**  We subtract the number of selections with at least two cyan balls from the number of ways we could select three balls if there were (at least) three balls of each color.

If there were (at least) three balls of each color, then the number of ways we could select three balls from the available colors is the number of solutions of the equation
$$c + m + y + k = 3 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers, which has
$$\binom{3 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{6}{3}$$
solutions, as you found in your first example.

From these, we subtract those selections in which $c \ge 2$.  If $c \ge 2$, then $c' = c - 2$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $c' + 2$ for $c$ in equation $1$ and simplifying yields
$$c' + m + y + k = 1 \tag{2}$$
Equation $2$ is an equation in the nonnegative integers with four solutions.

Hence, the number of ways three balls may be selected from one cyan ball, three magenta balls, three yellow balls, and three key/black balls is
$$\binom{3 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} - \binom{1 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{6}{3} - \binom{4}{3} = 16$$
which agrees with the answer we obtained above.

Comment: Thank you! The algebraic way does seem pretty interesting! By the way, I've added another answer below with some extra calculations, about the permutation way of counting (it is less optimal ofc, but a bit useful for more understanding). Could you please have a look? Do you think I am right with my extra calculations there, or do I miss anything? [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4613605/1137447)? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that order of selection is irrelevant.

I know of no elegant way to attack this problem.

I use **case-work**.

Either you have

- $3$ different colors: 
  $4$ ways, because there are $4$ different choices for the omitted color.
- $2$ of one color, $1$ of another color: 
  $4 \times 3$ ways of choosing first the *two-ball* color, and then the *one-ball* color.
- $1$ color (all 3 balls the same): 
  $4$ ways, because there are $4$ different choices for the color to be selected.

So, the number of distinct combinations is

$$4 + 12 + 4 = 20.$$

Answer (score 0):

The suggested above algebraic way of counting does seem more or less versatile.

As for another part of the question, it is of course possible to count **Combination with repetition** by using permutations, or sometimes even by enumerating the available options. It is not really optimal, but it might be useful for more understanding the concept.

So here is another, less optimal, way of tackling the issue.

> **Example-1, SOLUTION-3**: Subtracting from **Permutation with repetition** some (not all) options of **Indistinguishable
> permutations** (A similar approach is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3206527/1137447)).

a). Permutation with repetition = ${P_n}(k) = k^n = 4^3 = \underline{64}$

b). Permutation with indistinguishable objects = $\frac{(k_1 + k_2 + \ldots + k_i)!}{k_1! k_2! \cdots k_i!}$

**3 uniques**

b1-1). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CMY\} = 3!-\fbox{1} = 6-1= \underline{5}$

b1-2). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CMK\} = 3!-\fbox{1} = 6-1= \underline{5}$

b1-3). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CYK\} = 3!-\fbox{1} = 6-1= \underline{5}$

b1-4). Extra counts of the grouping $\{MYK\} = 3!-\fbox{1} = 6-1= \underline{5}$

**2 uniques**

c1-1). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CCM\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-2). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CCY\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-3). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CCK\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-4). Extra counts of the grouping $\{MMC\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-5). Extra counts of the grouping $\{MMY\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-6). Extra counts of the grouping $\{MMK\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-7). Extra counts of the grouping $\{YYC\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-8). Extra counts of the grouping $\{YYM\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-9). Extra counts of the grouping $\{YYK\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-10). Extra counts of the grouping $\{KKC\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-11). Extra counts of the grouping $\{KKM\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

c1-12). Extra counts of the grouping $\{KKY\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{1} = 3-1= \underline{2}$

**1 unique**

d1-1). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CCC\} = 1-\fbox{1} = \underline{0}$

d1-2). Extra counts of the grouping $\{MMM\} = 1-\fbox{1} = \underline{0}$

d1-3). Extra counts of the grouping $\{YYY\} = 1-\fbox{1} = \underline{0}$

d1-4). Extra counts of the grouping $\{KKK\} = 1-\fbox{1} = \underline{0}$

**Total** $= 4^3 - (5\times4) - (2\times12) - (0\times4) = 64-20-24 = 20$

> **Example-1, SOLUTION-4**: Enumerating and summing all the options

Look at the numbers in $\fbox{boxes}$ from the previous solution.

We have enumerated the options there, just without formulas. If we sum all the numbers up there, we will get the same result!

**Total** $= (4\times1) + (12\times1) + (4\times1) = 20$

> **Example-2, SOLUTION-3 and -4 methods**

Let's have a look at the above solutions, which might be helpful here.

Since we can have **only** `1` cyan ball, according to the task, then `c1-1)`, `c1-2)`, `c1-3)` and `d1-1)` are partially out of the game.

Thus, only corresponding lines for our **Example-2** will be different. Those lines are supposed to look like that:

$c'$1-1). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CCM\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{0} = \underline{3}$

$c'$1-2). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CCY\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{0} = \underline{3}$

$c'$1-3). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CCK\} = \frac{3!}{2!1!}-\fbox{0} = \underline{3}$

$d'$1-1). Extra counts of the grouping $\{CCC\} = 1-\fbox{0} = \underline{1}$

Therefore,

**Solution-5 Total** $= 4^3 - (5\times4) - (2\times9 + 3\times3) - (0\times3 + 1\times1) = 64-20-27-1 = 16$

**Solution-6 Total** $= (4\times1) + (9\times1) + (3\times1) = 16$

The answers are the same!

Comment: Your work is valid.  The reason I approached the second problem in the ways I did is that I wanted to show you efficient methods of solving the problem.